# Create my own Core Data Stack's advantages and usage

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

**Background:** Lately I'm reading 'CoreData by tutorials' to learn Core Data. The book shows me how to create a new Core Data Stack in code, and it encouraged us to do that.
**Question:**

1. Why need I write a new class to dealing with Core Data Stack rather than using the code that XCode provided to us in AppDelegate.swift, is there any advantages to do that?
2. The book's way to get ManagedObjectContext is pass the previous context to current Controller by segue. Like, firstly I initialize a context in `AppDelegate.swift`, and pass this value to a property named "context" in `topViewController` (A) of `self.window!.rootViewController as UINavigationController` . Secondly, if I want to use context in controller B, I need to declar a property named "context" in B, and pass A's context property through segue 
   `let dest = segue.destinationViewController as B
   dest.context = self.context`
   Is this the only way to use Context? I would rather use
   `if let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext` to get Context everywhere..
3. If I want to use model to manage Core Data thing like fetch, is it the correct way to pass "context", from controller, to init my model class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Separation of concerns. Without careful management, the application delegate quickly becomes the one-stop-shop for initialising parts of your application, which reduces readability / maintainability;
2. Personally, I find passing MOCs to controllers tedious and prone to mistakes. In a large project, I much prefer using a singleton like in [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit): `[[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext]`;
3. If I understand you correctly, you're asking how to create `NSFetchRequest` instances? If so, then yes, you use an MOC for the main queue (whether it's passed to the controller as a property or via another way is an implementation detail).

Comment: As for Q2, supposing I create a "MyCoreDataStack" class, can I init instances for each controller to get MOC rather than passing it? What harmful effect of creating many MOCs? Thank you very much!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating multiple MOCs, however, note that managed objects in one context are unique to that context. In short, it means unless you are extremely careful (and know the rules) when using managed objects across contexts, don't do it. In your situation, I'd recommend having one MOC for the main thread and use that single MOC in your controllers. You might also find this article helpful http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-overview.html